# Stopping Apache from listening in port 443?

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, https, ports

Pretty self-explanatory. Is there any way I can make Apache stop listening in port 443 (Https). So that it only listens on port 80 (http)?

I'm working on a Windows 7 PC.

Edit 1: I installed Apache with XAMPP. So i don't know how it came pre-configured.

Solution: There is a file in **"\apache\conf\extra"** called **http-ssl.conf** that had a command saying "Listen 443" (line 20). Just change it, delete it, or add a # before it to solve the issue.

Comment: How do you know it currently listens to 443?

Comment: I know it is currently listening on 443 because i can see it listed with cmd.exe "netstat -a -b"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had the same problem.
I found

```
Listen 443 https
```

in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` directory.

The README file in that directory states:

> This directory holds configuration files for the Apache HTTP Server;
>   any files in this directory which have the ".conf" extension will be
>   processed as httpd configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a "listen 443" statement in the .conf someplace... it will not listen on port 443.